# unity launcher from 12.10

Tags: unity

I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed on HP 4000 PC, how can I start Unity Launcher? Do I need to install any packages before I can use it. Any comments are highly appreciated. Thanks for your help.

Kevin

Comment: What do you mean by starting Unity Launcher ?

Comment: If you are new Unity , you'd better start with http://www.linuxinsider.com/story/76556.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the guy missed something while installing, because Kevin there is Unity menu defaultly on Ubuntu 12.10 or any new Ubuntu, i think there is something wrong with you copy or better if you made a print screen for us to see what is the real problem .